# Force text inside CSS triangle to stay in one line

Tags: css

I'm toying around with a triangle inside a div and want to place text inside that triangle. So far everything works as expected - only problem is the text gets warped at space - if there is no space between the words it all fits:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;z-index: 1;width: 0;height: 0;border-style: solid;border-width: 125px 125px 0 0;border-color: #1abc9c transparent transparent transparent;">
  <div style="top: -100px; left: 10px; right:0px; position:absolute;">
    <p>11 one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried making the text 1px and it still warps so it's obviously not a lack of space issue. Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: p {white-space: nowrap;} => http://jsfiddle.net/hbvpx1z7/1/

Comment: Thank you very much Eran, misterManSam and A.B. - both versions got the job done! I'm not that experienced with CSS so it was very frustrating why it's wrapping without any obvious reason - but now I understand why. I feel like both answers are correct and should be accepted?

Comment: @kat - We have compiled a single community answer that you can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

Firstly, let's clean up the HTML by separating the CSS.

#### The HTML

```
<div class="outerParent">
  <div class="innerParent">
    <p>11 one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The CSS

```
.outerParent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 125px 125px 0 0;
  border-color: #1abc9c transparent transparent transparent;
}
.innerParent {
  top: -100px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Better! Now, the first thing we see is that `.outerParent` has `width: 0`. This means that it's child `.innerParent` has no width. When text hits the edge of its container (which happens immediately because of `width: 0` on `.outerParent`), it will wrap any whitespace, and this is controlled by the [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> The white-space CSS property is used to to describe how white spaces inside the element is handled.

### How do I prevent this from happening?

The default white-space value is "normal" and this will wrap. Use the `white-space` property and set it to "nowrap":

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

The other option is to force the paragraph element to push outside of it's parent by giving it a width:

```
width: 50px;
```

### Working Example

```css
.outerParent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 125px 125px 0 0;
  border-color: #1abc9c transparent transparent transparent;
}
.innerParent {
  top: -100px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerParent">
  <div class="innerParent">
    <p>11 one</p>
  </div>
</div>
```